# ElasticSearch query with edge n gram along and operator is not giving expected result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index named 'company'. I have edge n gram analyzer set on company name field. So when I search with 'Morgan S', I would expect all records which starts with 'Morgan S' come up in the result such as 'Morgan Stanley', 'Morgan Sindall' etc..
I am having a query with 'and' operator also, but not getting expected result.

Below is my query :

```
        GET company/_search
        {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
            "query": "Morgan S",
            "fields": ["companyname.edge_ngram"],
            "operator": "and"
            }
        }
        }
```

I am having many records which starts with 'Morgan S', but not coming in results. I need to use AND operator so that I wont all records which starts with both Morgan and S.

Below is my index settings for that field.

```
        "companyname": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
            "edge_ngram": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": false,
                "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "entity_analyzer",
                "similarity": "boolean"
            },
            "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "similarity": "boolean",
                "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
            }
            },
            "norms": false,
            "analyzer": "entity_analyzer",
            "similarity": "boolean"
        }

        "analyzer": {
            "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                "filter": [
                "asciifolding",
                "lowercase"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
            }
```

Comment: Can you show how your analyzers look like?

Comment: @val - I removed search_analyzer from edge_ngram and it worked as expected. Thanks

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out